# Minimalistic html/javascript package for connecting to Phoenix channels

Tags: javascript, elixir

I'm looking for a way to create a minimalist demo package for frontend developers so that they can easily integrate channels between an Elixir/Phoenix api server and a mobile HTML5 app or (legacy) webapps not served by Phoenix.

NB: Javascript has never been my friend...

I'm doing tests with a Phoenix app generated with `--no-brunch`. `app.js` and `phoenix.js` are both located in `priv/static/js/`.

The `app.js` contains:

```
var socket = null
// Responds to a click on a "Connect" button on the GUI
function doConnect() {
    socket = new Socket("/socket", {params: {token: "abc"}})

    socket.connect()
    let channel = socket.channel("user:anonymous", {})
    channel.join()
    .receive("ok", resp => { console.log("Joined successfully", resp) })
    .receive("error", resp => { console.log("Unable to join", resp) })
}
...
// some other GUI callbacks
```

When I put in the `.html` file:

```
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/phoenix.js") %>"></script
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
```

I get in the console

```
ReferenceError: Socket is not defined
```

On the other hand, if I remove the inclusion of `phoenix.js` from the `.html` and put it in the `app.js` with `import "./phoenix.js"`, I get `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` in the console.

So where should go the `.js` files and how to include them to have a something that works ?

Maybe a related question is : how to use channels without brunch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/possible-to-use-phoenix-js-without-brunch/8856?u=mszmurlo). The call to the `Socket` constructor shouldn't be `socket = new Socket("/socket", {params: {token: "abc"}})` but `socket = new Phoenix.Socket("/socket", {params: {token: "abc"}})`.

Once this put in place, all is fine.